# Summing Values Based On Columns & Combining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense.

I have the following data:

```
AgtID | AppsStatusType | ColPrem
--------------------------------
1234  | PD             | 10.00
1234  | IS             | 50.00
5678  | CP             | 25.00
5678  | IS             | 25.00
5678  | PD             | 100.00
```

I need to group these by AgtID, and then get a sum of all IS or CP, and a sum of all PD. The end results should look as follows:

```
AgtID | IS/CP | PD
-----------------------
1234  | 50.00 | 10.00
5678  | 50.00 | 100.00
```

Any suggestions? I'm in SQL 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, for example, using sums with case when clauses.

```
select 
  AgtId,
  SUM(case when AppsStatusType IN ('IS', 'CP') then ColPrem else 0 end) as IS_CP,
  SUM(case when AppsStatusType = 'PD' then ColPrem else 0 end) as PD
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY AgtId
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10b17/1)

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. My brain isn't working today. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
AgtID , 
sum(case when AppsStatusType in ('IS','CP') then ColPrem else 0 end ) as [IS/CP],
sum(case when AppsStatusType in ('PD') then ColPrem else 0 end ) as [PD]
from your_table
group by Agtid
```